# Duplicate SQL model into Ruby on Rails postgresql model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am very new to Ruby on Rails development. Recently, there was a request to integrate an external database as part of our application. However, we were given SQL statements copied and pasted in a .docx file.

Example:

```
USE [portal]
GO
/****** Object:  User [admin]    Script Date: 9/11/2018 11:28:54 AM ******/
CREATE USER [admin] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[admin]
GO
/****** Object:  Schema [admin]    Script Date: 9/11/2018 11:28:54 AM ******/
CREATE SCHEMA [admin]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [admin].[ApplicationEnterprise]    Script Date: 9/11/2018 11:28:54 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [admin].[ApplicationEnterprise](
    [ApplicationID] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Level] [varchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Enterprise] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ApplicationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

.....

What is the best way for me to integrate this database into my application? I have cleaned up the SQL statements by removing "GO" and the [] etc. So far, my approach is to rewrite these statements into command lines to generate models.

Example:
rails g model ApplicationEnterprise ApplicationID:string ApplicationType:string Level:string

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, to go with the schema options. I mean you first need to convert your sql statements in to the required format of [`schema.rb`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you).

Then generate models from schema. Following article may help you to proceed.

https://codeburst.io/how-to-build-a-rails-app-on-top-of-an-existing-database-baa3fe6384a0

Comment: Thank you, I would try rewriting the statements for a start!